# PLSQL Statement Trigger Firing Twice

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a task to do where I have to implement an error trigger using a statement trigger in oracle SQL Developer. My table of data currently looks like this:

| ANUMBER | EXTRACT(YEARFROMAPPDATE) | APPCOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1999 | 2 |
| 4 | 2000 | 2 |

Essentially, the data counts the amount of applications an applicant makes per year. The job of the trigger statement is to verify a consistency constraint that an applicant can have no more than three applications per year.

Here is my trigger statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER application_count_constraint
--checks insert/update before 
BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON APPLIES
BEGIN
  
--loops through a select statement which shows how many applications each 
--person has per year
FOR x IN (SELECT anumber, 
                  extract(year FROM APPDATE), 
                  count(extract(year FROM APPDATE)) AS appcount
                  FROM APPLIES 
                  GROUP BY anumber, extract(year FROM APPDATE)
                  ORDER BY COUNT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM APPDATE)) DESC)
      LOOP 
          --counts if the value is going to be greater than 3
          IF (x.appcount + 1) > 3 THEN
            --raises application error (good error)
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'An applicant can not have more than 3 applications');
            EXIT;
          END IF;
      END LOOP;
END;
/
```

So to test the trigger, I simply add two applications for anumber 2. The first insert works fine because it hasn't violated > 3 applications per year.

The second insert does violate the consistency constraint and the trigger fires correctly. Here however is my question.

Here's the error I'm getting when the trigger fires:

```
Error starting at line : 58 in command -
INSERT INTO APPLIES VALUES( 000002, 00000002, TO_DATE('07-JUN-1999','DD-MON-YYYY') )
Error report -
ORA-20001: An applicant can not have more than 3 applications
ORA-06512: at "DON988.APPLICATION_COUNT_CONSTRAINT", line 15
ORA-06512: at "DON988.APPLICATION_COUNT_CONSTRAINT", line 15
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'DON988.APPLICATION_COUNT_CONSTRAINT'
```

I would like to know why the 'ORA-06512' error happens twice. I've tried a few different things but it only ever fires twice. If anyone could explain why that'd be a massive help.

Comment: I cannot answer your question. However, in a before-statement trigger you cannot really do what you want anyway, because you don't know which anumber(s) the insert or update will affect, You can use an after-statement trigger instead, where you see whether the insert or update has violated the limit for any anumber.

Answer (score 0):

The trigger doesn't fire twice. I'd guess the duplicated ORA-06512 message in the error stack is due to the way the compiler structures the code internally. Maybe there is a way to do a deep trace and get to the bottom of it, but I would just ignore it.

The trigger could be simplified to something like this, avoiding a loop and thus the double 6512 error:

```
create or replace trigger application_count_constraint
    before update or insert on applies
declare
    l_appcount number;
begin
    -- Detect case where more than 3 applications exist
    -- (assumes there were none before the current transaction and no other sessions are inserting/updating)
    select count(*) into l_appcount
    from   applies
    group  by anumber, to_char(appdate,'YYYY') having count(*) > 3
    order by count(*) desc
    fetch first row only;

    if l_appcount > 0 then
        raise_application_error(-20001, 'An applicant can not have more than 3 applications');
    end if;
exception
    when no_data_found then null;
end;
```

---

**Edit:** As @ThorstenKettner pointed out, attempts to use a row-level trigger fail with *ORA-04091: table is mutating* for multi-row inserts, so the version below won't work. This is in addition to being easily circumvented by concurrent inserts in two sessions as I mention below.

---

```
create or replace trigger this_wont_work
    before update or insert on applies for each row
declare
    appcount number := 0;
begin
    select count(*) into appcount
    from   applies
    where  anumber = :new.anumber
    and    trunc(appdate,'YEAR') = trunc(:new.appdate,'YEAR');

    if appcount >= 3 then
        raise_application_error(-20001, 'Applicant '||:new.anumber||' already has '||appcount||' applications in year '||to_char(:new.appdate,'YYYY'));
    end if;
end;
```

However, two sessions could easily bypass the check if each one inserted one or two rows and then committed a little later, as the check will only see committed rows. Therefore you might need to look at serialising updates somehow (the simplest approach might be to `lock table applies in exclusive mode;` at the start of the trigger), or else create an on-commit materialised view that aggregates the data and has a check constraint on the total count column (a bit of an exercise and I haven't tried it).

Comment: I don't recommend this approach. Such a before/after row trigger where you query the affected table can easily lead to ORA-04091: table is mutating.

Comment: It doesn't give a mutating table error. I'm not going to defend it though, because it isn't reliable in a multi-user system.

Comment: Please see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=ba45e34e24b5fa43c73cfecc3e244cf6

Comment: Oh, you are right, my apologies. It runs without error for single-row inserts, but fails with ORA-04091 for a multi-row insert.